# How to display data in two listbox of two different page at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, listbox

I have two asp file named `offPage.aspx` and `dgiPage.aspx`.

In the `offPage.aspx` file I have `4 textboxes, a button for input and a listbox` to show the input data

and in `dgiPage.aspx` I have another `listbox which will also show the same data`.

And there is also a `sql` file where the data will be saved after getting input via the 4 textboxes.

**I want to display data to both of the listboxes at the same time after clicking the button. How can I do that?**

I am sorry if this is a silly basic question, but I am a novice in C#.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Once you input the data from one page it get saved to the database and should be loaded to the second page. Is that your question?

Comment: yes that's what I want to know.

Comment: Once the user click on the save button from one screen, save the data to the database and load the second page (Use Response.Redirect to load the second page.) Load the data from the database in the Form_Load of the second page

Comment: I already tried the way you have mentioned.

Comment: Actually I want to show the data into both the listboxes(those in the first and second pages) at the same time after clicking the button on the first page.